# Xcode template has wrong copyright name, where is it being picked up from?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I made a mistake a while ago and enter my name as "Martin itt" which is wrong so i have updated my login etc and all seems to be well.. but when i create an new xcode project my comment headers are wrong.

If you look at the example below the create by is perfect and it has my correct name. But if you notice the Copyright then you will see "Itt" where it should be "Pitt".

Where is this value being picked up from?

I have edited my username and it reads perfect now..

Any ideas?

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  BasicInteraction
//
//  Created by Martin Pitt on 9/15/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Martin Itt. All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Copyright information by changing the Organization in your Project Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing set on the project, the default name and company information comes from your personal contact card in the address book / contacts app.

Answer (score 0):

What jrturton says above is incorrect and I can't stress enough how much it annoys me seeing people posting this without trying it. It does NOT pull from your contact card. It pulls from a specific template directory... and it pulls from your username for the computer. Change you're account username and you'll see what I mean. Please reference this directory and link for information regarding custom templates: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/XCode/Templates
[How to set ___COPYRIGHT___ in Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588846/how-to-set-copyright-in-xcode-4-5)