# How to set ___COPYRIGHT___ in Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, templates

The file tempates in Xcode 4.5 contain the following in the header

```
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PROJECTNAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//___COPYRIGHT___
```

How does one set the `___COPYRIGHT___` to a custom value.

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 13):

Changing the organization name will help you in set the COPYRIGHT value.

Please look at the screen , (Xcode4.5 screen shot)

[image: Please look at the screen , (Xcode4.5 screen shot)]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project in Xcode 4.4 or later, there is an Organization Name text field. The name you enter in the text field goes in the copyright notice, which looks similar to the following:

```
Copyright (c) 2012 Company Name. All rights reserved.
```

If you make a mistake entering a company name when creating the project, you can change the company name by selecting the project file from the project navigator and opening the file inspector.

Being able to set the company name is enough customization for most people. If you need to further customize the copyright notice, I recommend making a copy of Apple's file templates, and adding a custom copyright notice to the comments. More information on file templates is available in the following article:

[Creating Custom Xcode 4 File Templates](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/11/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/)